ROS2 rqt minimal UI example
I am trying to write a rqt plugin for ROS2 (jazzy, in case it matters).
The documentation on this seems to be very sparse.
It is especially the project structure that I don't understand:
What goes into the directories scripts, src/<pkg_name>, resource?
What should the setup.py look like?
Would someone happen to have a minimal example, for example on GitHub, for such a plugin?
I've studied the source code for built-in plugins such as rqt_graph, but they are a bit too complicated for a minimal example.
Thanks!
